# Image grid not rendering correctly

Tags: html, css, image-gallery

Good day.  I have an expandable image grid that I am having trouble getting to render correctly.  If you look at the first 3 images here: http://rthhockey.com/full-ice the expandable text content is rendering differently(text location) than the text content of image 4-12.  As I am adding custom content, the only thing that I can figure I am doing differently is adding the 
 tag.  I need separate lines in this content and 
 is the only way to add a line break that I know of.  Can this be causing the issue?  Or do you see something else that I am missing that is causing this distortion?  Thanks in advance for any assistance you may be able to give me.

MY CODE

```
CSS

html, body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", open sans;
}
h1 {
font-family: open sans;
color: #494949;
font-weight: bold;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

#gallerly.container {
  width: 100%;
}

#gallerly .image-viewer {
  position: relative;
}

#gallerly .image-viewer .preview {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1D1D1D;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

#gallerly .image-viewer .preview img {
  float: left;
  height: 280px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#gallerly .image-viewer > a > img {
  height: 150px;
}

#gallerly .image-viewer > a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#gallerly .image-viewer > a:hover {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;

}

#gallerly * {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.15s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.15s ease;
    transition: all 0.15s ease;
}

#gallerly .thumbnail.move-down {
  top: 346px;
}

#gallerly .preview .description {
}

#gallerly .preview a {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#gallerly .preview .wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#gallerly .preview .close-preview {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 5px;
}

#gallerly .preview .prev {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  top: 50%
}

#gallerly .preview .next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 50%
}

#gallerly .preview .preview-content {
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-right: 70px;
}

#gallerly .preview .title {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: semi-bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#gallerly .preview .description {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#gallerly .preview .arrow {
  border-bottom: 10px solid #222;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 0;
}

HTML

 <div id="gallerly" class="container">
      <div class="image-viewer">
        <a class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1YxdIW1.png?1" data-title="Jackson 5" data-description="3 Skaters run this drill at one time with all 3 attempting a shot on goal<br>F1 Skates top of circle and takes shot on goal<br>F2 Skates full circle without a puck<br>F3 Skates an inside/out pattern around face-off dot with puck, breaks on goal, and takes a shot<br>F1 picks up puck below far circle, matches timing of F2 through the neutral zone, and dishes pass to F2<br>F2 breaks in on goal with a shot while F1 crashes net for rebound"/></a>
        <a class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/awFVVcL.png" data-title="Chip To Speed" data-description="Form 2 equal lines in each corner<br>First player in each line(F1 & F2) skates to top of circle with F1 carrying a puck<br>F1 passes to F2 at top of circle<br>F2 then passes to first player in line 1<br>Line 1 then passes cross-ice to F1<br>F1 & F2 then loop through neutral zone and break in 2 x 0 vs goaltender"/></a>
        <a class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LHEOwdq.png"  data-title="4 Dot Skate & Shoot" data-description="Drill is designed to have players work on passing while skating hard around the cones and finish with a 2 on 0 shot<br>Players split into two corners with pucks in one corner<br>First player from each line skate on whistle passing puck back and forth as often as possible during first cycle through cones<br>Skaters will cycle a second time through cones breaking in on net 2 on 0 and taking a shot<br>Next two players in line will start as group 1 breaks in on goal"/></a>

        <a class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/qGNYydr.png" data-title="Figure Eight 2 x 0" data-description="First player in each line(F1 & F2) skates to top of circle with F1 carrying a puck

F1 passes to F2 at top of circle

F2 then passes to first player in line 1

Line 1 then passes cross-ice to F1

F1 & F2 then loop through neutral zone and break in 2 x 0 vs goaltender"/></a>
        <a class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/5uPxWsr.png" data-title="NASA Earth Image" data-description="Earth, also called the world[n 5] (and, less frequently, Gaia[n 6] or, in Latin, Terra[26]), is the third planet from the Sun, the densest planet in the Solar System, the largest of the Solar System's four terrestrial planets, and the only astronomical object known to accommodate life. The earliest life on Earth arose at least 3.5 billion years ago."/></a>
        <a class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/awFVVcL.png" data-title="NASA Earth Image" data-description="Earth, also called the world[n 5] (and, less frequently, Gaia[n 6] or, in Latin, Terra[26]), is the third planet from the Sun, the densest planet in the Solar System, the largest of the Solar System's four terrestrial planets, and the only astronomical object known to accommodate life. The earliest life on Earth arose at least 3.5 billion years ago."/></a>

        <a class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LHEOwdq.png" data-title="NASA Earth Image" data-description="Earth, also called the world[n 5] (and, less frequently, Gaia[n 6] or, in Latin, Terra[26]), is the third planet from the Sun, the densest planet in the Solar System, the largest of the Solar System's four terrestrial planets, and the only astronomical object known to accommodate life. The earliest life on Earth arose at least 3.5 billion years ago."/></a>
        <a class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/qGNYydr.png" data-title="NASA Earth Image" data-description="Earth, also called the world[n 5] (and, less frequently, Gaia[n 6] or, in Latin, Terra[26]), is the third planet from the Sun, the densest planet in the Solar System, the largest of the Solar System's four terrestrial planets, and the only astronomical object known to accommodate life. The earliest life on Earth arose at least 3.5 billion years ago."/></a>
        <a class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/5uPxWsr.png" data-title="NASA Earth Image" data-description="Earth, also called the world[n 5] (and, less frequently, Gaia[n 6] or, in Latin, Terra[26]), is the third planet from the Sun, the densest planet in the Solar System, the largest of the Solar System's four terrestrial planets, and the only astronomical object known to accommodate life. The earliest life on Earth arose at least 3.5 billion years ago."/></a>

        <a class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/awFVVcL.png" data-title="NASA Earth Image" data-description="Earth, also called the world[n 5] (and, less frequently, Gaia[n 6] or, in Latin, Terra[26]), is the third planet from the Sun, the densest planet in the Solar System, the largest of the Solar System's four terrestrial planets, and the only astronomical object known to accommodate life. The earliest life on Earth arose at least 3.5 billion years ago."/></a>
        <a class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LHEOwdq.png" data-title="NASA Earth Image" data-description="Earth, also called the world[n 5] (and, less frequently, Gaia[n 6] or, in Latin, Terra[26]), is the third planet from the Sun, the densest planet in the Solar System, the largest of the Solar System's four terrestrial planets, and the only astronomical object known to accommodate life. The earliest life on Earth arose at least 3.5 billion years ago."/></a>
        <a class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/qGNYydr.png" data-title="NASA Earth Image" data-description="Earth, also called the world[n 5] (and, less frequently, Gaia[n 6] or, in Latin, Terra[26]), is the third planet from the Sun, the densest planet in the Solar System, the largest of the Solar System's four terrestrial planets, and the only astronomical object known to accommodate life. The earliest life on Earth arose at least 3.5 billion years ago."/></a>
        <div class="preview hide">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <span class="arrow"></span>
            <a class="prev">← Prev</a>
            <div class="preview-content">
              <img src="" />
              <div class="content">
                <h3 class="title"></h3>
                <span class="description"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="next">Next →</a>
            <a class="close-preview">Close</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's definintely your line breaks that are causing the altered layout in this particular case. That's not the only issue, but it's one of them.

Given that you need to separate out your content into separate "chunks," it really looks like the element your looking for is an unordered list (`ul`).

That won't solve your layout problem by itself, but it will allow you to, well, list the steps in separate `<li>` elements.

---

Additionally, you have `.wrapper` set to `display: inline-block`. That means it will only stretch horizontally as far as it needs to accommodate its child content. When you shorten your lines with `<br>`'s, there's not enough content to push your container to the edges of its parent. This should probably be `display: block`, which will have the effect of forcing `.wrapper` to stretch the full width of its container (as long as you don't constrain it by setting a `width` or `max-width` or something like that.

---

I would really suggest altering your layout to avoid the use of `float`s. There's nothing intrinsically wrong with floating elements (the humble `float` has a long and venerable history, and can still be useful today), but the `flexbox` specification (and `grid` as well) can tend to give you more predictable control over your layout.

Here's a great overview of how `flexbox` works: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I've taken the liberty of adding some additional CSS rules to the end of your stylesheet to show one possible way (of a myriad ones) to convert this to more of a flexbox layout. Of course, your display needs may vary and you may need to adjust it accordingly.

As a sidenote, I would never nest my selectors as deeply as you are. Of course, I don't know the constraints you're working under and that level of specificity may be necessary in your case. I dunno.

```
    #gallery .preview .preview-content {
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-start;
      padding: 48px;
    }

    #gallery .preview .preview-content img {
      display: block;
      flex-basis: 250px;
      height: auto;
    }

    #gallery .preview .description {
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
```

I've also changed your HREF-less anchor tags to `<button>`'s, which is more semantically appropriate in this case. You would obviously need to style them to remove the browser's default user agent styling, but including an `anchor` with no HREF is definitely non-standard and probably wouldn't validate. Haven't checked.

Again, I would really investigate some newer layout possibilities (including `flexbox` and `grid`) and see if they don't strike you as useful. I would implement this layout very differently than you have, but that's down to personal preference, I suppose. Let me know if you need additional help.

Comment: I apologize for not getting back to you sooner but, had something come up just after I posted this.  Anyways, thanks so much for your input.  I really appreciate it.  In just adding the extra CSS you provided, this seems to have solved the problem.  I am still playing around with your other suggestions but, just adding the CSS is doing the trick for now. The only other issue I am trying to figure out is, in the description, I would like to align both the top of the image with the top of the description.  You can see updated example here:  http://rthhockey.com/full-ice

Comment: No worries! I looked at your site. Looks like you can just set `margin-top: 0` on the `h3`'s inside your expanding section. That will have the effect of aligning the top of the heading and the top of the image.